# Maven uses JRE7 instead of JDK?

Tags: eclipse, maven, java

Eclipse Juno Release
`Window / Preferences / Java / Installed Jres`
shows two installed Jres.
`jdk1.7.0_07` and `jre7`.

I get the following error when trying to `clean` and `process-classes` with maven:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler- 
plugin:2.4:compile (default-compile) on project reputation: Fatal 
error compiling: tools.jar not found: C:\Program 
Files\Java\jre7\..\lib\tools.jar
```

I added `tools.jar` as external jar already, out of desperation, but it didn't help. Why is maven trying to use the other `JRE`?

EDIT:

Compiler plugin excerpt from `pom.xml`

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.6</source>
        <target>1.6</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Can you please post your compiler plugin definition from your pom?

Comment: Do you get the same error if you do a mvn install from the command line on the project?

Comment: Nope. Completely different errors show up, stating that some packages are missing. Hmm, I will try to resolve them and see if it helps repairing eclipse enhance. Thank you for the tip! I am surprised at different outcomes to what I thought was the same execution.

Comment: Okay. The command `mvn clean process-classes` does it's job. Result is a `Build Success`. Unfortunately the eclipse enhance still gives the error which says `tools.jar` is missing.

Comment: I edited my answer below.  Give that suggestion a shot and let me know what happens.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to set your JAVA_HOME environment variable to the JDK directory.

EDIT:

In your installed JREs preferences window in Eclipse remove the JRE and select the JDK.  Also make sure that your project is set to use that JRE library (Right-click on the "JRE System Library" under your maven project structure in the explorer and set it as the "Execution Environment")

Comment: my JAVA_HOME environment variable (for user and system) is `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07` so it should be all set.

Comment: could it be a problem with win7 64bit and 32bit?

Comment: I don't think so.  Please post the build portion of your pom so we can see how you have the compiler plugin defined.

Comment: Success!
I altered the buildpath of the `JRE System Library` to the projects default library. That did'nt cut it. What i forgot to do was setting the right JRE in the `Run configurations` of my maven build. That adds up to an estimate of a thousand places where the JRE has to be configured. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just an FYI for next time. If you leave only the JDK in your "Window / Preferences / Java / Installed Jres" settings your run profile should default to "Project Settings" which will be that JDK so you won't need to change it every time.

Comment: But isn't something at some point going to need the Runtime Environment? Sorry if that sounds stupid, but I thought I would need this second JRE in some cases.

Comment: You can leave the jre on your machine, but there is no real need for it to be in your eclipse configuration.

Comment: @atrioom your fix worked for me, thank you. I had "Run Configurations" set to the old JRE values, which were selected as "Alternate JRE" under the "JRE" tab. I changed it to the default JRE, and voila!

Answer (score 8):

You should verify that the Maven "run configurations..." is connected to the correct JRE.  If the project JRE is correct but the run configuration JRE is incorrect you will get this error.  To fix, go Under Maven Build, choose the JRE tab.

Answer (score 3):

To configure maven builds to use the correct java execution environment you need to change the execution environment used by Maven.

**1. JRE Locations**

To set up JRE locations load the preferences window under Window\Prefences (Windows) or Eclipse\Preferences(OSX) or Edit\Preferences (Linux).

Expand the Java/Installed JREs option
Select the JDK of choice, or Add one if not configured.

[image: Installed JREs]

**2. Map Execution Environments**

To map any java version to a particular installed JRE select the Java/Installed JREs/Execution environment menu item

Select the appropriate default JRE installation for that version.

[image: Java Execution Environments]

**3. Run Configurations**

If you have particular run configurations, you can change/create specific run configurations and link a specific execution environment just to that command.

- To do that select Run/Run Configurations
- Select or create the run configuration.
- Select the Execution Environment tab.
- Select the appropriate execution environment for this command.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maven 2.0.9+ supports [toolchains](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-toolchains.html) that allows you can declare the version of the JDK required for the build.

Excerpt from the related Maven mini-guide:

```
<plugins>
  ...
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-toolchains-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>toolchain</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <toolchains>
        <jdk>
          <version>1.5</version>
          <vendor>sun</vendor>
        </jdk>
      </toolchains>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  ...
</plugins>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your installed JREs preferences window
"go to the submenu **Execution Environments** and **mark this JDK as compatible**" from 
[How to force Eclipse m2e plugin to use jdk for a project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25592290/how-to-force-eclipse-m2e-plugin-to-use-jdk-for-a-project)