# How to force Eclipse m2e plugin to use jdk for a project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2e

I'm using Maven with 'Eclipse Kepler JavaEE'. I have something like this in 'maven-compiler-plugin' :

```
<configuration>
    <source>1.7</source>
    <target>1.7</target>
</configuration>
```

Each time I'm changing somethin in 'pom.xml', eclipse forces me to perform 'Maven -> Update Project' and than project settings are changed to use JRE instead JDK and some maven builds are stopping to work.

The only solution I found to solve it is to set 
How I can set eclipse/m2e to use JDK is to define a path in maven-compiler-plugin. It is not good solution, since it is working only for my computer will fail for other.

I think there are some maven or m2e definitions saying "use jdk and not jre".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Eclipse, open **Window | Preferences | Java | Installed JREs**, make sure there's a JDK (and not just a JRE) for Java 1.7, then go to the submenu **Execution Environments** and mark this JDK as compatible with JavaSE-1.7.

After that, **Maven | Update Project** should work as desired.

Comment: Defining JDK compatable with JavaSE-1.7 in Execution Environments worked excellent. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see a JDK entry in >>Window | Preferences | Java | Installed JREs, 

Only a jre entry..

Comment: @Snedden27 in that case you have to add JDK there (just click "add" and point to you JDK location... if you even have one installed...)

Answer (score 0):

First `MVN_HOME` has to be setup and then the `JDK` as to browsed instead of `JRE`

```
Window--> Preferences--> Java-->Installed JREs
```

and select `JDK` (e.g. : `jdk1.7 or jdk1.8`)

the do mvn install it will work